# Scrollspy not working (BS 3 and Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, scrollspy

I'm building a long page and want the tabs of the navbar to become active as someone is scrolling on the page. Since I'm using Bootstrap 3, I thought scrollspy would work. However, I can't get it to work. Below is my code. I would appreciate any help :)

Code for the navbar

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <%= link_to image_tag("Logomark_Red.png", alt: "") + "  Title", root_url, class: "navbar-brand" %>
  </div>
  <div id="active-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><%= link_to "About", root_url(:anchor => "about") %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Projects", root_url(:anchor => "past-projects") %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Team", root_url(:anchor => "team") %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", root_url(:anchor => "contact") %></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

snippet of application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...head stuff....
  </head>
 <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>
 <body data-target="#active-nav" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
```

CSS for body

```
body{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

application.js File

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require colorbox-rails
//= require_tree .
```

HTML
(snippet just to show sections have id and that the nav links to those links)

```
<section id="about" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>content.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= image_tag("lego.jpg", width: "100%", alt: "") %>
            </div>
            <%= link_to "About Magnum Group", about_url, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The set up is correct, except you would not put a .row on the section #about (or any others). Also, you don't have bootstrap.min.js as one of the script files. Put it after the jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I put the row to create a full row and add an image on the background. I tried deleting to see if it fixed the problem and it did not. Also, I'm using [bootstrao-saas gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) to add bootstrap and it doesn't mention anything about a min file on the application.js. I checked that BS JS is working by seeing that the dropdown menu works on mobile devices (and it works) so I'm assuming the BS JS is OK. Any other thoughts?

Comment: That's right, bootstrap-sprockets is the .js file. A .row is not necessary it will add negative margin on the left and right, use nothing for full width. Do you have the rendered html file that you can link to?

Comment: Also, when you say not working, what is it not doing? Is it not making the .nav li.active?

Comment: Yeah, by not working I meant that it is not making the .nav li .active. You can see the site [here](https://guarded-oasis-5911.herokuapp.com)

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work but instead I created a javascript code that works. I hope it helps someone in the future.

```
    /* active on scroll */
marginTop = 50;
about = 849 - marginTop;
projects = 1388 - marginTop;
team = 1701 - marginTop;
contact = 2249 - marginTop;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    //Retrieve scroll distance from top
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    //Check if scrolled past div
    if(top >= about && top <= projects) {
        console.log('you are on about');
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).first().addClass( "active" );
    } else if (top >= projects && top <= team) {
        console.log('you are on projects');
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $( ".navbar-nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
    } else if (top >= team && top <= contact) {
        console.log('you are on team');
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $( ".navbar-nav li:nth-child(3)" ).addClass( "active" );
    } else if ( top >= contact) {
        console.log('you are on contact');
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).last().addClass( "active" );
    }
    else {
        console.log('tabs should not be active');
        $( ".navbar-nav li" ).removeClass( "active" );
    }        
});
```